# Unable to change value using setters and getters in OOP (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, getter-setter

I am unable to change the speed of ford Car, even after using setters and getters to update the speed to a new value (I don't want to use the assignment operator). Here's my piece of code :

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,speed,color):
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
    def set_speed(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed
ford = Car(100,'black')
audi = Car(200,'red')
bmw  = Car(250,'white')
ford.set_speed(400)
print(ford.get_speed())
print(ford.color)
```

Why I am not getting the speed of ford as 400, even after setting it?
I am getting the output as -

**100**
**black**

Comment: You aren't setting speed. Just change `self.value=value` to `self.speed=value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the attibute `value` in your setter, instead of the speed attribute, that is the one you are returning in your getter.
Just change the code inside your setter to:
`self.speed = value`